# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Christianity's [first moderator election](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: wax eagle] [image: Mason Wheeler] [image: Caleb] [image: El'endia Starman]

I believe this is the first time ever that we see the pro-tem moderator crew re-elected in its entirety. Please thank these folks for volunteering their time and evidently doing a fantastic job.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/2208002/0).

Comment: Whew! What a relief! Congratulations all!

Comment: I'm completely surprised at this turnout! jk

Comment: Hmm. I had thought the election was going to run a few days longer.  But it's good to see the community approves of the job we're doing.

Comment: Congratulations to all! Glad I at least beat out that "Exhausted" guy.

Comment: Not _quite_ in its entirety: **I'd like to take this moment to honor the memory of [Richard](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/84/richard), the [fifth pro-tem moderator](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/532/30) that did not join us in this election but whose contributions helped put us on course for this day. We wouldn't be where we are if it weren't for him.**

Comment: In the moderator election at http://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/1, it says that OpenSTV is for Windows of Mac. I just thought I'd point out that I was able to install it on Linux and analyze the results just fine.

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations!  Congrats to the not-so-newly elected mods. A huge congratulations to the C.SE community for making this milestone.